# How to create and access dictionary (or map or hashtable) with Octave

Tags: dictionary, struct, hashtable, octave

How can one create and access dictionary (or map or hashtable) with Octave?
I have tried a couple of ways, but maybe there are more efficient ways. Below is the code to show what I have tried. It uses inputs from .mat file provided here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4v1z1q04ivpgjvf/sample_input_dictionary.mat?dl=0

```
% Methods to build/use a dictionary on Octave

clear

tic

load sample_input_dictionary.mat;
pkg load general

toc

% Dict-based dictionary, using the "general" package: very slow to access
d_dict  = dict(nodes, num2cell(1:numel(nodes)));

toc

% Struct-based dictionary: slower to build, much faster to access
temp = [nodes', num2cell([1:numel(nodes)]')] .';
d_struct = struct(temp{:}); clear temp;

toc

% Is there an equivalent and more efficient cell-based dictionary?

% A different struct-based dictionary, which I could not build vectorially
t = struct();
for m=1:numel(nodes)
    t.(nodes{m}) = edges{m};
end

toc

% Example of accessing the above dictionaries
d_dict('1234') % this takes forever
d_struct.('1234')
t.('1234')
```

Comment: Please show some code and what you've tried so far, create a MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. I have added the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try **Structures** or **Cell arrays** for the same.

My preference is for **Cell Arrays**. But you try and understand what they do and decide appropriately.

It would be better if you can take a look at the documentation.

I am providing some links that might be useful.

Data Containers: [link to Octave Documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.0/Data-Containers.html#Data-Containers)

Structures: [link to Octave Documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.0/Structures.html#Structures)

Cell Arrays: [link to Octave Documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.0/Cell-Arrays.html#Cell-Arrays)

Comment: Many thanks. I have figured out how to use structures as dictionaries, although do not yet fully master this usage, in particular how to vectorize bulding the dictionary. As for cells, could you please use the example I provided in my edited question in order to show me how to build a dictionary using them, if more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

In version 4.4.0 a `containers.Map` data structure has been added. Below is the link to latest docs, version 6.2.0 at the time of writing this answer.

https://octave.org/doc/v6.2.0/containers_002eMap.html